# Не отображается кириллица в kivy в utf-8

Tags: python, kivy

Есть два файла, main.py и my.kv. Работаю в пайчарме. У обоих файлов стоит utf-8.

Код чистый, всё по минимуму:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Container(GridLayout):

    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Ну и my.kv:

````
<Container>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'текст'```

Windows 8.1

upd; конвертация .kv файла в windows1251 решила проблему, но теперь вопрос вот в чём. не отразится ли это на чём нибудь в будущем?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, в большинстве случаев помогает смена кодировки с windows-1251 на utf-8, но может быть и наоборот, как в моём примере.

Так же для windows 10 может сработать приём из другого вопроса: Параметры Windows -> Время и язык -> Язык -> Административные языковые параметры -> Изменить язык системы. Здесь ставим галочку "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире" Перезагружаем компьютер.

Плюс ещё такой часто советуемый вариант:

```
with open('kv_file.kv', encoding='utf-8') as kv_file:
    kv_file.read()
```

И вот ещё метод:

```
def load_all_kv_files(self, directory_kv_files):
for kv_file in os.listdir(directory_kv_files):
    kv_file = os.path.join(directory_kv_files, kv_file)
    if os.path.isfile(kv_file) and kv_file.endswith("kv"):
        with open(kv_file, encoding="utf-8") as kv:
            Builder.load_string(kv.read())
```